# AJAX serialize envia solo 200 registros

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código AJAX que envía a otra página via POST los datos que recolecta en un formulario.

```html
$(document).on('click', '.ConfirmaFacturacion', function(){

var dataString = $('.remitosForm').serialize();

        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
            url: "facturar_remitos_confirma.php",
            data: dataString,

  beforeSend: function(){
$("#ListaRemitos").html("<p align='center'><img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' /></p>");
},
error: function(data){
$("#ListaRemitos").html("Error en la actualizaci&oacute;n de datos. Intente nuevamente. -> "+data)

},

success: function(data) {
$("#ListaRemitos").html(data);

}
});



});
```

Y los recibo mediante PHP.

```html
<?php
$Cliente=$_POST['cliente'];
$Sucursales=$_POST['sucursales'];
$RemitosSeleccionados=$_POST['idremitoregistro'];

?>
```

El problema es que sólo envía a la otra página 200 registros y siempre hay más.

Comment: para cada post existe un limite de tamaño en la llamada, puedes particionar tus datos y enviarlos en direrentes post.

Comment: El problema también puede estar en tu servidor de aplicaciones te puede estar limitando el máximo de  llamadas, revisa esto, hay una directiva llamada `LimitRequestBody`, por cierto esta directiva es de Apache.